# Help needed in proving that x,y are integral over S

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am self studying commutative from Atiyah and Macdonald and I was trying an assignment. I got struck on this question.

> Let $k$ be a field and $X,Y,Z$ be variables. Set $R=k[X,Y,Z]/(X^2 -Y^3-1, XZ-1)$ and let $x,y,z \in R$ be the images of $X,Y,Z$ respectively. Set $t=x+z$. Let $S= k[t]$. Prove that $x,y$ are integral over $S$.

Attempt: x,y,z are images of X,Y,Z under R. I have to prove that x,y satisfies a polynomial equals 0  in with coefficients in k and variable being x+z with highest degree term coefficient being 1.

In ring R, $X^2-Y^3-1 =0$ and $XZ-1=0$. So, x=1/Z and $y=(Z^2 -1)^{1/3}$ and image of z =Z.

But, I am unable to proceed forward. I have to construct 2 polynomials over which x and y are integral.

Can you please help me by giving some hints?

Comment: Don’t mix up your variables, they are elements of different rings based on case. so $xz=1,$ not $XZ=1.$ $y=(Z^2-1)^{1/3}$ mixes cases, but also, it is bad form to reference an exponent of $1/3$ in a general ring, because (a) there isn’t always a value, and (b) when there is a value, there isn’t always a unique value. Finally, you seem to have confused $x$ and $z.$ It should be  $y^3=x^2-1,$ instead.

Comment: I've gave you enough information to prove all you asked here in a comment under your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4411959).

Comment: This is exercise 15.3 from Altman and Kleiman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice $t=x+z=x+x^{-1}.$

Use that to find a monic polynomial with coefficients in $k[t]$ and roots $x,z.$

After that, use your formula $y^3=x^2-1$ and the polynomial from the first step to find a monic polynomial with coefficients in $k[t]$ for $y.$

---

You could also use a general theorem to get that $y$ is integral after $x,z$ are integral.

The general theorem is:

> If $R_1$ is a subring of $R_2,$ and $u,v\in R_2$ such that $u$ is integral over $R_1$ and $v$ is integral over $R_1[u],$ then $v$ is integral over $R_1.$

Here, $R_1=k[t], R_2=R,$ $u=x,v=y.$

Then $y$ is integral over $R_1[x]=k[t,x]$, since $y$ is a root of $W^3-(x^2-1),$ and $x$ is integral over $R_1=k[t],$ so $y$ is integral over $k[t].$

But it is instructive and not too hard to find the explicit formula for a polynomial for $y.$

Comment: This theorem is not given in my notes. So, I will have to refrain from using it.